# ROS Answers SE migration: New RoS setup

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,
I'm totally new to RoS, so I need a little help to understand if I'm planning correctly what I want to do:

I would like to develop a simple bot that carries a camera and is remotely controlled (both using WiFi atm) with the idea of having a remote server image analisys (ideally OpenCV + cuda)

The current setup would be:

1. arduino for controlling the hardware (motors)
2. raspberry for controlling the arduino and video streaming
3. my laptop as remote server

For my understanding I need to install RoS on my laptop and on the Raspberry Pi, is this correct ?
would would be the ideal structure ?

Thank you very much,
Cesare

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206881/new-ros-setup/) by [Cesare](https://answers.ros.org/users/9941/cesare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2015-06-29**:
You might want to make sure that all the video stuff works with the raspberry pi you're using.  Not a lot of processing power on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The setup you describe sounds quite reasonable. As you said, you will need to install ROS on both the Raspberry Pi and the laptop. They will talk to each other via wifi. The Raspberry Pi could talk to the arduino any number of ways, but you could start by taking a look at [rosserial_arduino](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials) for some examples of getting communications up and running between Arduino widget and ROS.

You could run the ROS master (aka "roscore") on either side of the Wifi link, since you're teleoperating the robot and will be developing code actively for a while. If you eventually want to have the robot run autonomously and launch everything at power-up, many people run the ROS master on the robot to ensure that the robot's internal nodes connect regardless of the network status, but that's not terribly important when you are in the initial phases of hacking the system together.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0